# Resistivity dependance on temperature

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance

I'm just starting to study electricity and magnetism. The resistivity $\rho$ of a conductor is defined as

$$\rho = \frac {\mathbf E}{\mathbf j},$$

where $\mathbf E$ is the electric field and $\mathbf j = \sum_in_iq_i\mathbf v_i$ is the current density ($n$= concentration of carriers, $q$ their charges and $\mathbf v$ their velocities). I know that there's a linear approximation of $\rho(T)$, $T$ the temperature of the conductor, that says the resistivity rises when the temperature rises; but how from the definition of $\mathbf j$ can I say that an increase of the temperature means an increase in $\rho$?

I appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: On a separate note, you can't divide two vectors just like that. You better write it by dividing the magnitudes.

Comment: At elevated temperature the velocities becomes greater.

Answer (score 1):

You can not find the temperature dependence from this definition. You should look into the microscopic details of the process. For that, you should refer to the **[Boltzmann transport equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_equation)** from statistical mechanics. You can find it in a textbook on Statistical Physics or Condensed Matter physics.

In short, at high temperatures the resistivity is dominated by electron-phonon scattering, which gives rise to the linear dependence (See [here](http://large.stanford.edu/courses/2007/ap273/rogers1/) for example).